# Angular2 get data from class

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot get the databinding for `{{value}}` to work. Here is a simple example:

**app.component.ts**

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

    @Component({
        selector: "app",
        templateUrl: "./app/app.html"
    })

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        title:string = "aaaaa";
        ngOnInit() {
            console.log("Application component initialized ...");
        }
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <section>
        <p>test Display.</p>
        <nav>
            <p>{{title}}</p>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

`{{title}}` was always blank.I check DOM that `<p>` is created.

Comment: No need for constructor as it does not inherit from anything.

Comment: your template name reads `app.html` but it is in fact `app.component.html`

Comment: sounds like a problem that [cannot be reproduced](https://plnkr.co/edit/LV0zJaWevBEoKR4HPQ39?p=preview)

Comment: if you have no error in the console, that's not the problematic part of your code...

Comment: the console is blank.not any red warning or error is matterd.

Comment: what if you put a public in front of your title:string = "aaaaa"; ...so public title:string = "aaaaa";

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I had try it but it didn't work.

Comment: sorry but do you see test Display rendered?

Comment: Check [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fZlXGoHwXDhh2oRamhDr?p=preview)  that solves the problem. Mostly it seems to be configuration issues.

Comment: the paragram tag is rendered.Exactly,I remove this project and restart.it works.

Comment: it's really wired who can explain?I had start with gulp(uglify,sass,syncbrower) and didn't set the spicilize configuration.

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl(app.html) name and the name of html(app.component.html) is varies.check that one

Comment: I fixed on my post.Not this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Let's try

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public title:string;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.title = "aaa"
        console.log("Application component initialized ...");
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not matter, value assigned in on init or out of init.